# powerBI embedded report in Salesforce

Tags: powerbi, salesforce, lwc

I have a powerBI report that I embedded in Salesforce as an LWC. the report has multiple tabs, the LWC shows the report but only the default tab and no option to switch tabs in there. is there a way we can show the tabs toggle in Salesforce?

I have this apex class code that is running the LWC, not sure what should be added there

`public with sharing class PowerBiEmbedManager {

```
public PowerBiEmbedManager() {      
 
}

public class ClientCredentialPostData {
    public String client_id;
    public String client_info;
    public string client_secret;
    public String scope;
    public string grant_type;
    public String getPostData(){
      return 'client_id=' + this.client_id + 
            '&client_info=' + this.client_info +
            '&client_secret=' + this.client_secret +
            '&scope=' + this.scope +
            '&grant_type=' + grant_type;
    }
}

public class ClientCredentialResponse {
  public String access_token;
    public String expires_in;
    public String ext_expires_in;
    public String token_type;
}

public class PowerBiReport    {
    public String id { get; set; } 
    public String reportType { get; set; } 
    public String name { get; set; } 
    public String webUrl { get; set; } 
    public String embedUrl { get; set; } 
    public boolean isFromPbix { get; set; } 
    public boolean isOwnedByMe { get; set; } 
    public String datasetId { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class PowerBiEmbedToken    {
    public string token { get; set; } 
    public string tokenId { get; set; } 
    public DateTime expiration { get; set; } 
}

public class PowerBiReportData    {
  @AuraEnabled
    public String workspaceId { get; set; } 
  @AuraEnabled
    public String reportId { get; set; } 
  @AuraEnabled
    public String name { get; set; } 
  @AuraEnabled
    public String embedUrl { get; set; } 
  @AuraEnabled
    public String embedToken { get; set; } 
  @AuraEnabled
    public DateTime embedTokenExpires { get; set; } 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String error { get; set; } 
 }

public static String getPowerBiAccessToken() {

    // get auth settings from Custom Metadata Type reconrd
    Power_BI_Auth_Setting__mdt authSetting = Power_BI_Auth_Setting__mdt.getInstance('PowerBiApp');
    string TenantId = authSetting.TenantId__c;    
    string ClientId = authSetting.ClientId__c;    
    string ClientSecret = authSetting.ClientSecret__c;        

    // construct URL for client credentials flow
    String aadTokenEndpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + TenantId + '/oauth2/v2.0/token';

    // prepare HTTP request 
    HttpRequest reqClientCredentialsFlow = new HttpRequest();
    reqClientCredentialsFlow.setMethod('POST');
    reqClientCredentialsFlow.setEndpoint(aadTokenEndpoint);        
    reqClientCredentialsFlow.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // compose data for POST body
    ClientCredentialPostData postData = new ClientCredentialPostData();
postData.client_id = ClientId;
postData.client_info = '1';
postData.client_secret = ClientSecret;
postData.scope = 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default';
postData.grant_type = 'client_credentials';        
    String postBody = postData.getPostData();
    reqClientCredentialsFlow.setBody(postBody);

    // send HTTP POST to execute client credentials flow
    Http http = new Http();        
    HttpResponse response = http.send(reqClientCredentialsFlow);

    // extract and return app-only access token for service principal
    String responseJson = response.getBody();
    ClientCredentialResponse responseData = (ClientCredentialResponse)JSON.deserialize(responseJson, ClientCredentialResponse.class);
    String access_token = responseData.access_token;         
    return access_token;
}

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static PowerBiReportData getEmbeddingDataForReport(String WorkspaceId, String ReportId) {
   
        
    // get access token for Authorization header
    String access_token = getPowerBiAccessToken();        

    // Call to Power BI Service API to get report data for embedding        
    HttpRequest reqGetReport = new HttpRequest();
    reqGetReport.setMethod('GET');
    String urlGetReport = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + WorkspaceId + '/reports/' + ReportId;
    reqGetReport.setEndpoint(urlGetReport);
    reqGetReport.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
    
    Http http = new Http();        
    HttpResponse response = http.send(reqGetReport);
    
    // check response for success
    if(response.getStatusCode()!=200){
        System.debug('ERROR --- Getting Report Data --- ERROR');
        System.debug('Status Code: ' + response.getStatusCode());
        PowerBiReportData getReportError = new PowerBiReportData();
        getReportError.error = 'Get Report Error: ' + response.getStatus();
        return getReportError;            
    }            

    // extract Power BI report data from JSON response
    String responseJson = response.getBody();
    PowerBiReport powerBiReport = (PowerBiReport)JSON.deserialize(responseJson, PowerBiReport.class);
    
    // send report info to debug window
    System.debug('id: ' + powerBiReport.id);        
    System.debug('reportType: ' + powerBiReport.reportType);        
    System.debug('name: ' + powerBiReport.name);  
    System.debug('webUrl: ' + powerBiReport.webUrl);      
    System.debug('embedUrl: ' + powerBiReport.embedUrl);        
    System.debug('isFromPbix: ' + powerBiReport.isFromPbix);        
    System.debug('isOwnedByMe: ' + powerBiReport.isOwnedByMe);        
    System.debug('datasetId: ' + powerBiReport.datasetId);        

  // Call to Power BI Service API to get embed token for report        
    HttpRequest reqGetEmbedToken = new HttpRequest();
    reqGetEmbedToken.setMethod('POST');
    String urlGetEmbedToken = 'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/' + WorkspaceId + '/reports/' + ReportId + '/GenerateToken';
    reqGetEmbedToken.setEndpoint(urlGetEmbedToken);
    reqGetEmbedToken.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);    
    reqGetEmbedToken.setBody('{"accessLevel": "View", "datasetId": "' + powerBiReport.datasetId + '"}');

    HttpResponse responseEmbedToken = http.send(reqGetEmbedToken);

    // check response for success
    if(responseEmbedToken.getStatusCode()!=200){
        System.debug('ERROR --- Getting Embed Token --- ERROR');
        System.debug('Status Code: ' + responseEmbedToken.getStatusCode());            
        PowerBiReportData getEmbedTokenError = new PowerBiReportData();
        getEmbedTokenError.error = 'Get Embed Token Error: ' + response.getStatus();
        return getEmbedTokenError;            
    }            

    // extract Power BI embed token and expiration
    PowerBiEmbedToken embedToken = (PowerBiEmbedToken)JSON.deserialize(responseEmbedToken.getBody(), PowerBiEmbedToken.class);
    
    // send report info to debug window
    System.debug('EmbedToken: ' + embedToken.token);        
    System.debug('EmbedToken ID: ' + embedToken.tokenId);        
    System.debug('expiration: ' + embedToken.expiration);
    
    // create custom remote-able object to return to caller in browser 
    PowerBiReportData powerBiReportData = new PowerBiReportData();        
    powerBiReportData.workspaceId = WorkspaceId;
    powerBiReportData.reportId = ReportId;
    powerBiReportData.name = powerBiReport.name;
    powerBiReportData.embedUrl = powerBiReport.embedUrl;
    powerBiReportData.embedToken = embedToken.token;
    powerBiReportData.embedTokenExpires = embedToken.expiration;
    
    return powerBiReportData;            
        
}
public static PowerBiReportData dummyCode(String WorkspaceId, String ReportId){
    PowerBiReportData powerBiReportData = new PowerBiReportData();        
    Integer i = 0;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    return powerBiReportData;        
}
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In your LWC javascript file where you are setting up the embed configuration, there is a setting option to make the page navigation visible. Here is a sample config:

```
var config = {
              type: 'report',
              id: reportId,
              embedUrl: embedUrl,
              accessToken: token,
              tokenType: 1,
              settings: {
                panes: {
                  filters: { expanded: false, visible: true },
                  pageNavigation: { visible: true}
                }
              }
            };
```

Simply define the settings object, nest in the panes object, and define the pageNavigation with visibility set to true. Make sure to clear your cookies on your browser when testing the changes so as to clear out the old cached version of the embedded report.